# sort linux in UTF8

Tags: linux, sort

A sorted file (with `LANG = fr_FR.UTF-8`) contains :

```
Bassano del Grappa - Remondini, Giuseppe, II (1745-1811)
Bassano del Grappa - Remondini, Giuseppe, I (1672-1742)
...
Zurich - Wolf, Johannes (1564-1627)
Zurich - Wolf, Johann Rudolf, I (15..-1624)
```

No problem with accentuation. But, why `II` before `I` or `Johannes` before `Johann` ?

(that's on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)).

Comment: Can you add sample lines showing diacritical examples leading to the "null sort" issue your are referring to in a comment when using `LC_ALL=C sort`?

Comment: That would seem to indicate `I` sorts before `1` in that locale. What's the output of `printf 'I\n1\n' | sort`?

Comment: With any locale :printf 'I\n1\n' | sort
1
I
The sort "null" : Évora - Burgos, Andrés de (15..-1579)
Évreux - Ancelle, Jean-Jacques-Louis (17..-18.. ; imprimeur-libraire)
Évreux - Ancelle, Jean-Jacques (1787-18..)
are at the end of the file

Answer (score 0):

When using a non POSIX locale `GNU sort` doesn't lead to the expected output under Linux. This doesn't happen under Solaris even with GNU `sort`. See Stéphane Chazelas an indepth explanation [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/423345/generate-the-collating-order-of-a-string/426369#426369).

Your best bet is to switch to the `POSIX` locale with which at least you'll get a consistent output:

E.g.:

```
$ cat f
w
e
é
f
 z
  x
```

Linux:

```
$ LC_ALL=C sort f
  x
 z
e
f
w
é
$ LC_ALL=fr_FR.utf8 sort s
e
é
f
w
  x
 z
```

Solaris:

```
LC_ALL=C sort s 
  x
 z
e
f
w
é
$ LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8 sort s
  x
 z
e
é
f
w
```

Comment: But, this cannot explain the observed behavior... The ASCII code of `(` is 40 which is lower than `A` (65). So, the `II` should appear after the `I(`, which is not the case. And,  also, `ne` is higher than `nR`. So, none of the sample do match with what you say. Or, am I missing something ?

Comment: Oddly this substitution makes it possible to get rid of the problem with I but not with the 'n'  ???

Comment: cat toto <br/>
Bassano del Grappa - Remondini, Giuseppe, II (1745-1811) <br/>
Bassano del Grappa - Remondini, Giuseppe, I (1672-1742)<br/>
Zurich - Wolf, Johannes (1564-1627)<br/>
Zurich - Wolf, Johann Rudolf, I(15..-1624)<br/>
cat toto |tr ' ' '\001' | sort | tr '\001' ' '<br/>
Bassano del Grappa - Remondini, Giuseppe, I (1672-1742)<br/>
Bassano del Grappa - Remondini, Giuseppe, II (1745-1811)<br/>
Zurich - Wolf, Johannes (1564-1627)<br/>
Zurich - Wolf, Johann Rudolf, I(15..-1624)<br/>

Comment: Sorry i don't know how to make CRcat toto    
Bassano del Grappa - Remondini, Giuseppe, II (1745-1811)    
Bassano del Grappa - Remondini, Giuseppe, I (1672-1742)    
Zurich - Wolf, Johannes (1564-1627)    
Zurich - Wolf, Johann Rudolf, I(15..-1624)    
cat toto |tr ' ' '\001' | sort | tr '\001' ' '  
Bassano del Grappa - Remondini, Giuseppe, I (1672-1742)  
Bassano del Grappa - Remondini, Giuseppe, II (1745-1811)  
Zurich - Wolf, Johannes (1564-1627)  
Zurich - Wolf, Johann Rudolf, I(15..-1624)

Comment: mip22, there is no way to insert newlines in comments. This kind of formatted information should be appended to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by replacing all spaces by the pattern 000 before sorting (it's probably a space problem !! ??). 
Thank you all, specially Stéphane for the link to "Generate the collating order off a string".