# Why does gnu `sort` ignore non-alpha charectars?

Tags: bash, shell-script, sort, gnu

I was expecting @'s to be sorted together, but they interleaved with the non-@ versions.  Does sort have an option for ASCII sorting?  I didn't see something obvious in the man page.

```
$ echo '@x
> @y
> @z
> x
> y
> z' | sort
x
@x
y
@y
z
@z
```

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/429194/sort-linux-in-utf8 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is locale-dependent. man sort includes:

```
*** WARNING *** The locale specified by the environment affects sort order.  
Set LC_ALL=C to get the traditional sort order that uses native byte values.
```

You can set that just for the one command, like:

```
... | LC_ALL=C sort ...
```

Comment: Or better use just `LC_COLLATE=C` which would work just as well. No need to throw the baby out with the bathwater -- an UTF-8 `LC_CTYPE` is perfectly fine, it's  `LC_COLLATE` which is unasked for trouble.

Comment: @user414777 True here. I tend to globally export LC_ALL at the top of my scripts, because I rely on awk, sort, uniq, ls, tr etc to play nicely together.