# Why does sort say that ɛ = e?

Tags: sort, locale, unicode

`ɛ` ("Latin epsilon") is a letter used in certain African languages, usually to represent the vowel sound in English "bed". In Unicode it's encoded as U+025B, very distinct from everyday `e`.

However, if I `sort` the following:

```
eb
ed
ɛa
ɛc
```

it seems that `sort` considers `ɛ` and `e` equivalent:

```
ɛa
eb
ɛc
ed
```

What's going on here? And is there a way to make `ɛ` and `e` distinct for `sort`ing purposes?

Comment: sorting rules are called 'collation', if that helps your googling

Comment: Try to put a certain number of `ea` mixed with `ɛa` inside a text file and sort it. You will see that it always sorts `ea` before `ɛa`. So, no they are not considered equal.

Comment: Might be an obvious point, but I haven't seen it suggested explicitly yet: if you are sorting words in $(certain_african_language), the natural thing to do is setting the locale to $(certain_african_language).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni A very good point! Unfortunately I haven't been able to find any locale made for this language.

Comment: epsilon is not latin but greek

Comment: @GermánBouzas This is specifically "Latin epsilon", a form designed to fit in with the Latin alphabet. They look pretty much the same, but Latin epsilon is U+025B, while Greek epsilon is U+03B5.

Comment: @Draconis Thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 69, accepted):

No, it doesn't consider them as equivalent, they just have the same primary weight. So that, in first approximation, they sort the same.

If you look at /usr/share/i18n/locales/iso14651_t1_common (as used as basis for most locales) on a GNU system (here with glibc 2.27), you'll see:

```
<U0065> <e>;<BAS>;<MIN>;IGNORE # 259 e
<U025B> <e>;<PCL>;<MIN>;IGNORE # 287 ɛ
<U0045> <e>;<BAS>;<CAP>;IGNORE # 577 E
```

`e`, `ɛ` and `E` have the same primary weight, `e` and `E` same secondary weight, only the third weight differentiates them.

When comparing strings, `sort` (the `strcoll()` standard libc function is uses to compare strings) starts by comparing the primary weights of all characters, and only go for the second weight if the strings are equal with the primary weights (and so on with the other weights).

That's how case seems to be ignored in the sorting order in first approximation. `Ab` sorts between `aa` and `ac`, but `Ab` can sort before or after `ab` depending on the language rule (some languages have `<MIN>` before `<CAP>` like in British English, some `<CAP>` before `<MIN>` like in Estonian).

If `e` had the same sorting order as `ɛ`, `printf '%s\n' e ɛ | sort -u` would return only one line. But as `<BAS>` sorts before `<PCL>`, `e` alone sorts *before* `ɛ`. `eɛe` sorts after `EEE` (at the secondary weight) even though `EEE` sorts after `eee` (for which we need to go up to the third weight).

Now if on my system with glibc 2.27, I run:

```
sed -n 's/\(.*;[^[:blank:]]*\).*/\1/p' /usr/share/i18n/locales/iso14651_t1_common |
  sort -k2 | uniq -Df1
```

You'll notice that there are quite a few characters that have been defined with the exact same 4 weights. In particular, our ɛ has the same weights as:

```
<U01DD> <e>;<PCL>;<MIN>;IGNORE
<U0259> <e>;<PCL>;<MIN>;IGNORE
<U025B> <e>;<PCL>;<MIN>;IGNORE
```

And sure enough:

```
$ printf '%s\n' $'\u01DD' $'\u0259' $'\u025B' | sort -u
ǝ
$ expr ɛ = ǝ
1
```

That can be seen as a bug of GNU libc locales. On most other systems, locales make sure all different characters have different sorting order in the end. On GNU locales, it gets even worse, as there are thousands of characters that don't have a sorting order and end up sorting the same, causing all sorts of problems (like breaking `comm`, `join`, `ls` or globs having non-deterministic orders...), hence the recommendation of [using `LC_ALL=C` to work around those issues](/q/87745).

As noted by @ninjalj in comments, glibc 2.28 released in August 2018 came with some improvements on that front though AFAICS, there are still some characters or collating elements defined with identical sorting  order. On Ubuntu 18.10 with glibc 2.28 and in a en_GB.UTF-8 locale.

```
$ expr $'L\ub7' = $'L\u387'
1
```

(why would U+00B7 be considered equivalent as U+0387 only when combined with `L`/`l`?!).

And:

```
$ perl -lC -e 'for($i=0; $i<0x110000; $i++) {$i = 0xe000 if $i == 0xd800; print chr($i)}' | sort > all-chars-sorted
$ uniq -d all-chars-sorted | wc -l
4
$ uniq -D all-chars-sorted | wc -l
1061355
```

(still over 1 million characters (95% of the Unicode range, down from 98% in 2.27) sorting the same as other characters as their sorting order is not defined).

See also:

- [What does "LC_ALL=C" do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87745)
- [Generate the collating order of a string](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/423345)
- [What is the difference between "sort -u" and "sort | uniq"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/76049)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! For completeness, what does `<PCL>` stand for? The others seem to be Capital, Miniscule, and Basic?

Comment: @Draconis, _collating-symbol <PCL> # 16 particulier/peculiar_

Comment: Indeed if we put a bunch of `ea` and `ɛa` mixed together in a file we see that `sort` sorts all `ea`s before `ɛa`s.

Comment: From glibc 2.28, the codepoint should be used as a fallback for a 4th level weight, see https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=glibc.git;a=commitdiff;h=bc1d41044c0cf9f0214acdbfd79b6cd11fd1e8c1 https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14095

Comment: With the weights of U+025B changed to `<U025B> <S025B>;<BASE>;<MIN>;<U025B> % LATIN SMALL LETTER OPEN E`

Comment: is `strcollate` a function in `sort.c`?

Comment: @ninjalj that's great news! Thanks. I'm looking forward to that version landing in Debian. I'll have some editing to do in a few of my answers here including  this one.

Comment: @cat, sorry, I meant `strcoll()`, see edit.

Comment: @ninjalj, actually in my tests 2.28 seems to be about as bad as 2.27 (see edit). `sort` seems to be a lot slower as well (though that may be down to me running that ubuntu 18.10 on a virtual machine).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: The L with middle dot has specific rules for it (e.g, there are rules for `U0137`, `U004C_00B7` and `U004C_0387` giving weights `<S006C>;"<BASE><VRNT1>";"<CAP><MIN>";<U013F>`, DUCET has similar rules). Regarding the million characters that sort as equal, non-assigned codepoints have no weights assigned to them, plus there was some trouble in glibc with sorting some codepoints at astral planes, see: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=22898 But, for the most part, actual assigned characters should sort in a somewhat sane way, barring bugs.

Comment: @ninjalj, yes that's what I meant, that _special rule_ doesn't make any sense. `uconv -x '[[:assigned:]]>;\n>;' < all-chars-sorted | wc -m` returns 837841 even with that older version of `uconv`, we're still far from 1061355. Last time I looked at it (probably a few years ago now), there were a few bug reports related to that glibc bug/misfeature and more in software that use it. I'd expect most of them to still be there. I'll do some digging if you want when I have a moment. Are you involved in the glibc development?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: nope, I'm just a bystander. Looking at it a bit more, it seems the problem here is that while the UCA has up to 5 levels (L1-L4 plus Ln for a final "Identical" tie-breaking level), glibc abuses the 4th level for tie-breaking (e.g: in https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=glibc.git;h=a93fecdcece3e2178834f4b4868b2309b0158753). So yep, there's still much to improve.

Answer (score 15):

man sort:

```
   ***  WARNING  ***  The locale specified by the environment affects sort
   order.  Set LC_ALL=C to get the traditional sort order that uses native
   byte values.
```

So, try: `LC_ALL=C sort file.txt`

Comment: That works! But why does the default locale consider these completely separate codepoints to be the same? I'm curious why this happens.

Comment: @Draconis What is "the default locale"?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski An empty value of the environment variable; I'm not sure what locale that corresponds to.

Comment: @Draconis if `LC_ALL` is empty, `sort` may use other `LC_*` variables, `LANG` or some configuration files.

Comment: `LC_COLLATE` is the string-sort-specific one, `LANG` is the extra-general one.

Comment: @NieDzejkob, if LC_ALL, LANG and LC_COLLATE are all empty or unset, `sort` will use the C/POSIX locale for collation, not some configuration file. Empty localisation variables are required to mean the same as unset ones.

Answer (score 8):

The character ɛ is not equal to e, but some locales can gather these signs close together upon collation. The reason for this is language specific, but also some historical or even political background. For example most people probably expect that *€uro currency* comes close to *Europe* in dictionary.

Anyway to see what collation you are currently using run `locale`, the `locale -a` will give you the list of locales available on the system and to change collation say to `C` just for one sorting run `LC_COLLATE=C sort file`. Finally to see how different locales can sort your file try

```
for loc in $(locale -a)
    do echo ____"${loc}"____
    LC_COLLATE="$loc" sort file
done
```

Pipe the result to some greping tool to choose locale that fits your need.

Comment: This is a wonderful explanation, but the symbols seem to be considered identical, not just close together.

Comment: No, they're not considered identical. Add a plain `ea` line to the file, then with `sort -u` you will get both `ea` and `ɛa` in the output. The best strategy vs. collate is **avoid** (`export LC_COLLATE=C`). Otherwise, many ugly things will happen (eg. `/tmp/[a-z]` in `bash` will match `/tmp/a` and `/tmp/A` but not `/tmp/Z`).

Comment: @mosvy Huh, interesting…so they are considered the same for ordering purposes but not for uniqueness purposes?

Comment: they're not considered the same. see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/252426/308316) an explanation about it.

Comment: @mosvy: Character ranges [a-z] and [A-Z] have been fixed recently, see https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=23393 and https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=glibc.git;a=commit;h=7cd7d36f1feb3ccacf476e909b115b45cdd46e77

Comment: @mosvy: BTW, there are still things that need fixing, e.g: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1631472

Comment: Good answer except for your crazy and completely made up "€uro" example.

Comment: @ninjalj, that may be fixed in the glibc `fnmatch()` and regexp ranges, but not in some like `bash` that implement its ranges by itself using `strcoll()`. ksh93 never had the problem because its range implementation uses `strcoll()` and also check the case of range ends and only match on lowercase characters if both ends are lower case. zsh ranges don't have the issue as it's done based on code point, not strcoll().